# How to check if the list of numbers are sorted?

Tags: awk, sed, sort

How to check if numbers from list file are increasing?

Example list1:

```
658
659
663
```

will get "OK".

Example list2:

```
658
664
663
```

will get "FAIL".

Example list3:

```
23
24
25
26
```

will get "OK".

Comment: Might be able to just run sort -nc...

Comment: need to get expected output ok/fail

Answer (score 15):

You can use `sort -nc filename` to validate if the file is in incremental order or not (containing numbers only).

```
sort -n -c filename >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "OK" || echo "FAIL"
```

Or in short (note the upper `-C` "`like -c, but do not report first bad line`"), also using `-u` option to check for a strictly ascending order as well as `-g` option to have more number formats to be supported (like `+2`, `0x10`, `1.2e+3`, `infinity`, ... ) suggested by [@StéphaneChazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas):

```
sort -guC filename && echo "OK" || echo "FAIL"
```

Note: *if you don't want report "FAIL" on the repeated same numbers, omit the `-u` option at above.*

Comment: You can also add a `-u` option to check for a strictly ascending order (like in Raman's approach). See also the `-g` option with GNU `sort` for more number formats to be supported (like `+2`, `0x10`, `1.2e+3`, `infinity`...).

Comment: thank you, I have included your comment in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

```
awk 'BEGIN {res = "OK"}
     NR > 1 && $1 <= prev {res = "Fail"; exit}
     {prev = $1}
     END {print res}'  file
```

This awk solution should work. Set the `res` variable to OK from the outset and then check the first space delimited field in the file against the `prev` variable. If this line's `$1` is less than the previous, set `res` to `Fail` and stop reading. Finally at the end of the script, print the `res` variable.

Comment: I get fail on that  
1234
1235
1236

Comment: Hmmmm,works fine for me,

Comment: This would fail on a correctly ascending negative series like -3 -2 -1 (not sure whether that matters to the OP).

Comment: @Kusalananda, I took the liberty to fix that part.

Answer (score 3):

Another trick with **`join`** command:

```
join --check-order file file &>/dev/null && echo "OK" || echo "FAIL"
```

Tests:

```
$ cat a1
11
33
22
$ join --check-order a1 a1 &>/dev/null && echo "OK" || echo "FAIL"
FAIL
```

---

```
$ cat a2
11
22
33
$ join --check-order a2 a2 &>/dev/null && echo "OK" || echo "FAIL"
OK
```

Comment: Nice idea, but watch out - `join` doesn't check for a numeric sort.  For example a file containing `1\n100\n11\n` is reported to be sorted.